# Report viewer not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer

I have problem with report viewer using c#. I create a report and add report viewer to my form and add report to report viewer using code, but it does not work and shows a message

> The source of the report definition has not been specified

This is my code :

```
public partial class ShowReportsForm : Form
{
    string STUTS, ID;

    DataSetForAllProducts datasetforallprodect = new DataSetForAllProducts();
    DataSetForAllProducts datasetforsingleproduct = new DataSetForAllProducts();

    ReportDataSource ReportDataSorce1 = new ReportDataSource();
    BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();

    public ShowReportsForm(string stuts)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        STUTS = stuts;
    }

    public ShowReportsForm(string stuts, string id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        STUTS = stuts;
        ID = id;
    }

    private void ShowReportsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (STUTS == "getallproducts")
        {
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
            "Prodects_Management.RPT.ReportAllProducts.rdlc";
            BS.DataMember = "PRODECTS";
            ReportDataSorce1.Value = BS;
            BS.DataSource = datasetforallprodect;
            DataSetForAllProductsTableAdapters.PRODECTSTableAdapter cstp = 
            new DataSetForAllProductsTableAdapters.PRODECTSTableAdapter();
            cstp.Fill(datasetforallprodect.PRODECTS);
            ReportDataSorce1.Name = "DataSetForAllProducts";

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSorce1);
        }
        else if(STUTS == "getsingleproduct")
        {
        }

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
     }
  }
```